# multi-threaded process crash with gdb hitting breakpoint

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gdb

I am trying to debug a multi threaded program using gdb. I have attached the process to the gdb and set a breakpoint in interested thread with an intention of step over when the breakpoint is hit. But the program crashes at the moment when the breakpoint is hit. It looks like the trap handler is not getting set for the other thread other than the current active one. I have used gdb before on multi threaded processes and never faced this issue earlier.

Comment: Is your multi-threaded program dynamically linked?

Comment: yes it is dynamically linked.

Comment: Which version of `gcc`, GNU libc, Linux kernel, and GDB are you using. Try at least GDB 7.6